# Python script to make every combination of a string with placed characters

Tags: python, string, random, combinations, permutation

I'm looking for help in creating a script to add periods to a string in every place but first and last, using as many periods as needed to create as many combinations as possible:

The output for the string `1234` would be:

```
["1234", "1.234", "12.34", "123.4", "1.2.34", "1.23.4" etc. ]
```

And obviously this needs to work for all lengths of string.

Comment: Hi, can you write the code which you have tried so far?

Comment: import regex as re


def combination(string):
    len_string = len(string)
    stringsep = re.findall(".", string)
    for i in range(0,len_string):

        word1 = []
        for x in range(0, i):
            word1.append(stringsep[x])
        if i == 0:
            pass
        else:
            word1.append(".")
        #print(word1)

        for y in range(i,(len_string)):
            word1.append(stringsep[y])
            print(''.join(word1))


combination("string")

Answer (score 4):

You should solve this type of problems yourself, these are simple algorithms to manipulate data that you should know how to come up with.
However, here is the solution (long version for more clarity):

```
my_str = "1234"         # original string

# recursive function for constructing dots
def construct_dot(s, t):
    # s - the string to put dots
    # t - number of dots to put

    # zero dots will return the original string in a list (stop criteria)
    if t==0: return [s]

    # allocation for results list
    new_list = []

    # iterate the next dot location, considering the remaining dots.
    for p in range(1,len(s) - t + 1):

        new_str = str(s[:p]) + '.' # put the dot in the location
        res_str = str(s[p:]) # crop the string frot the dot to the end

        sub_list = construct_dot(res_str, t-1) # make a list with t-1 dots (recursive)

        # append concatenated strings
        for sl in sub_list:
            new_list.append(new_str + sl)

    # we result with a list of the string with the dots.
    return new_list

# now we will iterate the number of the dots that we want to put in the string.
# 0 dots will return the original string, and we can put maximum of len(string) -1 dots.
all_list = []
for n_dots in range(len(my_str)):
    all_list.extend(construct_dot(my_str,n_dots))

# and see the results
print(all_list)
```

Output is:

```
['1234', '1.234', '12.34', '123.4', '1.2.34', '1.23.4', '12.3.4', '1.2.3.4']
```

Comment: Thanks so much: Could you help explain what this does please? : str(s[:p])

Answer (score 2):

A concise solution without recursion: using binary combinations (think of `0`, `1`, `10`, `11`, etc) to determine where to insert the dots.

Between each letter, put a dot when there's a `1` at this index and an empty string when there's a `0`.

```
your_string = "1234"

def dot_combinations(string):
    i = 0
    combinations = []

    # Iter while the binary representation length is smaller than the string size
    while i.bit_length() < len(string):
        current_word = []
        for index, letter in enumerate(string):
            current_word.append(letter)
            # Append a dot if there's a 1 in this position
            if (1 << index) & i:
                current_word.append(".")
        i+=1
        combinations.append("".join(current_word))
    return combinations

print dot_combinations(your_string)
```

Output:

```
['1234', '1.234', '12.34', '1.2.34', '123.4', '1.23.4', '12.3.4', '1.2.3.4']
```